# how to create Webservice in asp.net for requesting page filled in textbox using authorized password and username

Tags: asp.net

i'm trying to make webservice ,
it includes usename field, password field and page-name field and click button

after clicking click-button, using webservice , username and password must be authenticated
and page-name in text-field must be browsed in the browser.

I'm trying in localhost.
Can anyone provide me information, as i'm trying first time.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there's a lot of big concepts in the question you just asked.   I would probably start with looking at ASP.NET's membership provider.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff184050.aspx

That link is a nice basic walkthrough on how to create a simple login form.  You could likely extrapolate to add a text box where a user could type a URL.

Comment: i'm feeling difficult to understand the contains of above http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff184050.aspx, is there other simpler way ?

Comment: Well, proper authentication is not a trivial thing to do.  You could probably throw together a simple html form with some text boxes, but if you're interacting with a server, there's going to be some necessary complexity involved.  Not sure if there's a silver bullet on this one.

Comment: Is there any other solution help ?. provide me simpler ways of doing it.If possible web-pages with image will be helpful for me.